# AddEventListener для class

Tags: веб-программирование, javascript, html

Почему не работает addEventListener для className в моем случае?

```
<a href="#" class="fileSelect"><img class="ad" src="img/add.png"></a>
<input class="image" name="images[]" accept="image/*" style="display:none" type="file">
```

**JS**

```
var fileSelect = document.getElementsByClassName("fileSelect"),
fileElem = document.getElementsByClassName("image");

fileSelect.addEventListener("click", function (e) {
    if (fileElem) {
        fileElem.click();
    }
    e.preventDefault(); 
}, false);
```

Если class изменить на id, то все работает.

Comment: [массив элементов](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_document_getelementsbyclassname.asp) != [элемент](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_document_getelementbyid.asp)

Comment: @Yura Ivanov, это не массив, а NodeList.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Как сделать, чтобы работало:

```
// Привязка события к конкретному элементу
function bindEvent(element, type, handler) {
    if(element.addEventListener) {
       element.addEventListener(type, handler, false);
    } else {
       element.attachEvent('on'+type, handler);
    }
}

// Привязка события к выборке элементов
function bindEventAll(NodeList, type, handler) {
    for (var i = 0; i < NodeList.length; ++i) {
        var element = NodeList[i];
        bindEvent(element, type, handler);
    }
}

// Инициация события на элементе
function fireEvent(element, event) {
    var fireOnThis = element;
    if (document.createEvent) {
        var evObj = document.createEvent('MouseEvents');
        evObj.initEvent(event, true, false);
        fireOnThis.dispatchEvent(evObj);
    } else if (document.createEventObject) {
        var evObj = document.createEventObject();
        fireOnThis.fireEvent('on' + event, evObj);
    }
}

// Инициация события на выборке элементов
function fireEventAll(NodeList, event) {
    for (var i = 0; i < NodeList.length; ++i) {
        var element = NodeList[i];
        fireEvent(element, event);
    }
}
```

Допустим, есть такая разметка:

```
<div class="initiator">Click me!</div>
<div class="target">And me!</div>
```

Сделаем так, чтобы кликая по **initiator**, мы инициировали клик и по **target**.

```
var initiator = document.getElementsByClassName('initiator');
var target = document.getElementsByClassName('target');

bindEventAll(initiator, 'click', function () {
    // Передаем событие дальше
    fireEventAll(target, 'click');
});

bindEventAll(target, 'click', function () {
    alert(this.className + ' has received your click');
});

// выведет: target has received your click
```

**[Демонстрация](http://jsfiddle.net/fwcm48gw/1/)**

**Update:** складывается такое ощущение, что вы смешиваете функционал jQuery и vanilla javascript. jQuery - это библиотека. Функций click() и preventDefault() в обычном javascript нет, если вы их сами не напишите.

Comment: да работает, но теперь ошибку выдает на fileElem.click(). Пишет что типа нету такой функции.

Comment: @ager32, я обновил свой ответ.

Comment: Вопрос решен, спасибо.

Comment: @VenZell почитайте внимательно здесь http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-2-Events/events.html#Events-Event

Comment: @eicto, я был не прав. Очевидно, что плохо знаю спецификацию и поспешил с выводами